# Shared Object issue when i compile for Ad Hoc or store

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad, air, adobe

i had an issue with Shared Objects in Adobe AIR for iPad.

I luckily were able to find it a solution but i really wanted to know WHY i had to do this.

The problem was the following:
I have an app that uses shared objects to store some data. It worked just fine when i compiled it on desktop or when i made a debug directly from Flash Pro to my ipad2. But i realized that it didn't worked when i uploaded the app to the store, and it didn't work either when i made a compilation with an ad hoc provisioning profile.

After a while, i realized that the problem were on the lines that had something like:

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("appData");

if( so.data.varName != undefined ) ...
```

when i commented the if, the app on ad hoc started to work. So i replaced that line with:

```
if( so.data.hasOwnProperty("varName") ) ...
```

and it worked!

Can someone explain me WHY i had to do this? it worked just fine on Flash Pro when testing the swf, and also when i debug the app from flash pro directly to my ipad, but it didn't worked when i compiled for ad hoc or for the app store. Any ideas?

Thank you!

---

ps: can it be possible that the default value for the dynamic properties of an object when they don't exist is different from the constant undefined? why then was this working when i used just the Swf?
i filled a textfield with the value and the type of one inexistent property on an ad hoc compilation and it said the same as on the swf, value: undefined, typeof: undefined

Answer (score 0):

There's an ongoing issue with Adobe AIR that always evaluates a negated boolean as true when built in ios release mode. The current workaround is to change the if statement from

```
if (!bool) {
  foo();
}
else {
  bar();
}
```

to

```
if (bool) {
  bar();
}
else {
  foo();
}
```

See https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1335342

Comment: Thank you for your answer! unfortunetly i couldn't reproduce the error as you described it. I have tested the following code in my desktop and in my ipad using Ad Hoc provisioning profile and it worked fine and consistently, so i think it might be something else.

    var bool:Boolean = false;
    if(!bool){
        trace("true");
    }else{
        trace("false");
    }

It returned "true" in my desktop and in my ipad. Any other ideas?